# Android Custom Calendar for bookings

Tags: android

I am busy writing an android app that needs to have a booking system. It needs to have a Calendar that users can view or navigate (Day | Month | Year) and click on to book events on certain days. Thus in the day view, you will see the booked events. These events will then be saved in the database under that users id.

The problem is to get a calendar view to do this without reinventing the calendar or programming a calendar from scratch. As far as I know, android does not have support for this or at least not for API 10. The app needs support from API 10 and upwards.

Also, I don't want to use the built in Google calender that comes with the phone or any calendar application running on the phone, because that places some restrictions such as, the device needs to have that app installed etc.

The screenshot shows more or less the view I am looking for. If I can get that type of view working with day , month and year views working, that will be great. Any help,resources, libraries etc. will be useful.

Please see the screenshot to see what I am more or less trying to do.

http://i50.tinypic.com/1q0u49.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ashutiwari4 , The Gregorian Calendar class in java does not have any views, it is a class that represents the Gregorian Calendar and it's functionality. It has built in members and functions to print basic information, e.g. time of day, day of motnh, year etc.... So you can use that class to create a new instance of a Date object. Then you can manipulate that date object, for example if the user clicks on the "next day" button to view the next day on the calendar, you can add one day to your date object. You have to build your own views using a gridview (or any other view that works for you)